# 'this' returning either 'Object' or 'Window' inside the same object

Tags: javascript

Now that's a new one for me. I searched around but can't find the solution elsewhere.

I've got this code (coffeescript) :

```
PositionDetector = ->

    detectPosition : ->
        console.log this # outputs 'Object' (OK)
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.locationHandler)

    locationHandler : (position) ->
        console.log this # outputs 'Window' (WHY??)

positionDetector = new PositionDetector()
positionDetector.detectPosition()
```

(or the corresponding compiled javascript, if you prefer) :

```
var PositionDetector = function() {

      detectPosition : function() {
        console.log(this); // outputs 'Object'
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.locationHandler);
      },

      locationHandler : function(position) {
        console.log(this);  // outputs 'Window'
      }
}

var positionDetector = new PositionDetector();
positionDetector.detectPosition();
```

Question is, why does the first 'this' output 'Object' and the second one 'Window'?

[Live demo in a Codepen](http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/JddOVv?editors=001)

Comment: @vinayakj: If you mean the code right at the top, because it's not JavaScript, it's CoffeeScript. Jeremy posted the JavaScript translation of it in the second block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question is, why does the first 'this' output 'Object' and the second one 'Window'?

`this` is set primarily by how a function is *called* (for now*), not where it's defined. In the first case, the way you're calling the function is through an object reference (`positionDetector.detectPosition()`), and so the JavaScript engine sets `this` to be the object you used as part of the expression making the call. In the second case, the function isn't being called as part of an expression retrieving the function reference from an object property, so `this` takes its default value (the global object in loose mode, `undefined` in strict mode). Here's a simpler example:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
};
var f = obj.foo;
obj.foo(); // `this` is `obj` during the call
f();       // `this` is not `obj` during the call
```

To solve it, you could use `Function#bind` to use a specific `this` value during the callback:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.locationHandler.bind(this))
```

`Function#bind` creates a function that, when called, will call the original file with a specific `this` value (and any optional arguments you provide).

More about `this` *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

* "for now": ES6 introduces CoffeeScript-style *arrow functions*, which have a `this` value that's set by the context in which the function is created. That wouldn't really help you here, but it makes my usual "...is set primarily by how a function is called..."* statement no longer true. :-)

Comment: Wonderful and swift double answer, thanks to both of you. I can't validate both answers though, but I can +1  :)

Comment: Also writing a closure can correct the situation. Just my fifty cents.

Answer (score 3):

Because `this` depends on the caller. The caller to `this.locationHandler` is `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback)` and it calls the function like `callback()`, notice, there is no dot in that call, meaning there is no value for `this`. The solution is to set `this` permanently using `bind`:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.locationHandler.bind(this))
```

Remember, general rule: no dot, no `this`, unless you used `call` or `apply` to call the function, or `bind` to set the value of `this` forever.

Comment: Wonderful and swift double answer, thanks to both of you. I can't validate both answers though, but I can +1  :)

Answer (score 0):

Both T.J. Crowder & elclanrs are right.

As a brief explanation:
"this" refers to object context (A.K.A. scope) and it does not work exactly as you expected in javascript unfortunately ,

- detectPosition() is called in the context of PositionDetector by you.
- locationHandler() is called in the context of window  which is the global object and the event originator.

IMHO this situation renders Javascript stupid. 
There are two methods to overcome this effect. First is the "bind" method as they have shown. The second one is the magical "closure" generation.

Comment: I had never encountered this situation in an object with many methods, maybe because I was calling the methods from outside, not from each other. Yet I don't thing javascript is stupid :) It's temperamental, but that's why I like it! Thanks for your input.

Comment: :D Yes. I really love them.