# $.each changes this context inside a module closure

Tags: jquery, this, self, javascript

I have build a standard javascript module (pattern) which contains a number of 
private methods and variables.  I am finding that I am fighting with maintaining the `this` context to point to my module after using `$.each`.

I know that the jQuery `$.each` method creates a closure and hence a new "context", however I do want to continue to have `this` referring to the module.  I've found that calling the my module's private function (`initFruit()` in sample) using the initFruit.call() and passing in a `self` copy of `this` (which is "in scope") works *for that function*, however as soon as that function calls *another* function, the context is lost again.

I really don't want to be calling all my private functions with .call() all the time simply because I made use of `$.each` further up the call stack so how do I use `$.each` without having my original context lost?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BloodBaz/zz11n5wp/1/

Comment: I've had the same kind of issue a while ago. I have asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983887/this-returning-either-object-or-window-inside-the-same-object), maybe the answers provided can help you.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyThille. Interesting.  Your example is passing the sub function through an intermediary `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` call which I'm not doing in this example.

Answer (score 0):

In a scope context where you define inner closures that substitute `this` (say: 90% of the cases in private "methods"), the easiest way to have the "global scope"'s `this` element is to define a variable, typically `self` right in the first line of your main code block. In your case the "global" `this` is `Window`, thus here is what I'd do, in few words replacing "this" with "self" when you want to reference the object and `this` only when you want to reference the inner closure:

```
var MyModule = (function ($) {
    var self = {};

    var privateFunction = function () {
        console.log(self);
    }

    self.init = function () {
        privateFunction(); // exposes all the public methods of self, keeping the "private" functions private
    };

    return self;
}(jQuery));

MyModule.init();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zz11n5wp/2/

Comment: Thanks.  I've augmented your example slightly to monitor `self` and `this` at multiple function calls.  Both are showing a valid `this` anyway as well as access to other private items.  This suggests I am doing something *wrong* as your example is demonstrating what I am wanting but not getting.

https://jsfiddle.net/BloodBaz/zz11n5wp/5/

Comment: If you're in an inner scope, you'll be able to continue see the variables in the outer one. This means that you can access the private functions and variables inside your scope, but you won't be able to access them from outside. See example: https://jsfiddle.net/zz11n5wp/6/

I'm not sure what's going wrong in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try binding the function to the scope you want? Kind of like below

```
var self = this;    
$.each([1,2,3,4], function(index, item) {
  // do something
  // self === this
}.bind(this));
```

Or if you need older browser support, try using a library like lodash or something to do it. Or [jquery's $.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/zz11n5wp/3/

Comment: Thanks @vernak2539.  I thought `bind()` might play a part in the solution.  It does indeed present the desired `this` to the anonymous function which is great.  However, as soon as I call `initFruit()` (and indirectly `initFruitSub()`) the context changes once again back to the global context.  Is it normal to expect to have to use `.call()` or `.bind()` for ALL function-to-function calls inside the module in order to maintain the `this` of the module? Thanks.

Comment: Scope is a funny thing in JS. it really depends on your situation and where the functions get called from. In this case you may have to use call/apply in order to get the desired functions. or you could bind the functions at the top level. To be honest, binding all the time is really not worth it (looks weird sometimes), just to be able to use "this". Aliasing "this" is actually a good idea in some cases